# How to sync with remote repo after a failed pull

Tags: git, merge, pull

I am working on a project that is a branch of a remote repository.  From time to time, I sync up my project with changes to the remote by doing `git pull upstream master`.

Here is what happened:

- yesterday, after commiting my last local changes, I did `git pull upstream master` #1.
- got new files, had to merge a few of them, and then tried to build the project. The build failed.
- I then unstaged all changed files and ran `clean all`, incorrectly assuming that I undid that `git pull upstream master`.
- then I made a few more local changes and committed them.
- in the meantime, the remote has been fixed, and I want to sync up.
- however, when I did `git pull upstream master` #2, I only got changes made to the remote since the pull #1.

How can I get all changes from the remote including the ones I originally got in the pull #1 without losing the local changes I have made since the pull #1?

UPDATE 1:
I just did `git merge --abort` and that seems to have undone the last `pull` (#2).
Then I created a new branch `save-local-changes`, which, if necessary, I hope to use to merge my local changes back into master after I sync it with the remote.  How do I now redo (force) that pull #1?

Comment: When you committed your local changes, have the unstaged files been still around? You do not mention that you reset the changes to your pristine, local, version...

Comment: @j6t - please see also my update of the question.  I have not done a reset of the local (master) branch yet. But I am starting to think I need to in order to be able to redo the pull #1, followed by a merge (cherry-picking?) of the local changes from my `save-local-changes` branch.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just checkout the current state of the remote master

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

And then merge in your local changes from your `save-local-changes` branch